# Помогите Python ошибка хочу чтобы все что я указал в переменную сохранилось даже после перезагрузки кода

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Всем привет у меня произошла проблема в коде Python вот код:

```
import random
 words = []
 print("Введите текст для остоновки напишите stop")
 random.shuffle(words)
 while True:
 a = input("Вы:")
random_number = random.choice(words)
print(random_number)
words.append(a)
if a == ("stop"):
    break
```

Я хочу чтобы то что ввел пользователь добавлялось в словарь точнее в переменную words все успешно но после перезагрузки данные переменной words онуляется.

Как сделать так чтобы словарь сохранялся?

Пожалуйста помогите

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы данные сохранялись, вам нужно куда-нибудь сохранить их, это можно сделать в отдельном файле с помощью json. Вот код, который сериализирует (сохраняет) данные в json файл:

```
import json

data = {"name": "Sergey", "age": 30, "city": "Moscow"} # Данные, которые хотим сохранить (должны быть в виде словаря)
with open("data.json", "w") as f: # Открываем файл в режиме перезаписи, если его не существует, то он создастся
    json.dump(data, f) # Сохраняем данные в файл с именем data.json
```

А чтобы наоборот загрузить данные в python код (десериализировать), вам надо использовать такой код:

```
import json

with open("data.json", "r") as f: # Открываем файл в режиме чтения
    data = json.load(f) # Берем из json файла данные и сохраняем их в переменную
```

Comment: я попытался сохранить мою переменную но к сожелению выбило ошибку
не подскажите как ее решить и пожалуйста можете просто дать исправленный мой код с вашими внесениями буду благодарен

data = {words} # Данные, которые хотим сохранить (должны быть в виде словаря)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: data = {“words”: words}

Comment: Теперь точно спасибо прям реально выручил